# How to scale down a p5.js canvas without losing resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I have a p5.js canvas on my website, contained within a `canvasDiv` class, and I have a script that goes to the website and clicks the canvas, which downloads it etc. How do I scale down the canvas so that it doesn't take up most of the screen, while still keeping the 1000x1000px resolution? Thanks and have a good day!

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvasDiv">
  <script src="sketch.js" id="astrum"></script>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
  <script src="shapes.js"></script>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#canvasDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
```

**JS**

```
function setup() {
  const myCanvas = createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  myCanvas.parent('canvasDiv');
  background(40);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
}


function mousePressed(){
  if(mouseX > 0 && mouseX < width){
    if(mouseY > 0 && mouseY < height){
      save("AM.png");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the most efficient or useful option, but you could try `transform: scale{0.5)` in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [create graphics](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) and draw to the graphics buffer with [image()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image) on the canvas.
when you want someone to download make the download from the graphics buffer and not from the canvas.
saveCanvas(selectedCanvas, [filename], [extension])

Comment: I am glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a hidden canvas behind, i think css has a property:

#real-Canvas {
hidden: true
}

Afterwards you could have the image or whatever you have scaled down on the first canvas that users see, as like a preview type thing, you could also do this with createGraphics i guess.

this is basically the same answer as DavidWeiss'.